# Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-card-actions'

Tags: html, angular10

I don't really know how to fix this problem, usually we have this problem because "CommunModule" or "BrowserModule" are not imported, but in my case everything is already imported...
So if you see something I forgot, please tell me.

btw I'm using Angular 10

**Here is the way I import in app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HomeComponent } from './Home/home.component';
import { MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatCarouselModule } from '@ngmodule/material-carousel';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { HomeDialogComponent } from './home-dialog/home-dialog.component';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    HomeDialogComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatCarouselModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-card-actions *ngif = "tile.seeMore === true">
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog()">See more</button>
 </mat-card-actions>
```

Comment: Have you tried without the spaces around the `=` character? Pretty sure `*ngIf = ...` is interpreted as `*ngIf (attribute)` instead of `*ngIf (Directive)`.

Comment: Yes, and still have the same error :(

Comment: And you’ve checked that you’re using `*ngIf` with a capital “I”, not `*ngif`? Your error message and code both use a lowercase “i”.

Comment: It works now thank you very, I did a basic error